# Declare a JavaScript function which can hide the label of the calling HTML element

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
<label for="ABC">LABEL1</label><input type="text" id="ABC" onFocus="label();"/>
<label for="DEF">LABEL2</label><input type="text" id="DEF" onFocus="label();"/>
```

**JavaScript**

I want to declare a JS function with name "label" which can find the label of the element from which it has been called and hide it.

**Problem Solved!** Thank you all for the support! :D

Comment: That sounds like a fantastic idea! Better get to work on it.

Comment: If I wasn't browsing on a tablet I'd probably do this for the rep, despite no effort being shown. Sometimes I feel so very, very dirty.

Comment: @TGH: You would? Why?

Comment: @CrazyTrain I find that this is a perfect use case for JQuery it just cuts down on the amount of code. Besides JQuery is already included in most projects these days anyway

Comment: @TGH: You're pulling my leg, right?

Comment: Most, but not all. And it's in no way required. Plus, barring the older browsers, I don't see that it particularly simplifies things, given the predictable html structure and the explicit relationships between elements.

Comment: I see your point, but I think that JQuery, with less effort, can make this more robust against DOM changes if you restructure the UI a little and put a wrapper around the two elements and use find(..).

Comment: @TGH: Are you reading from your manual of jQuery talking points? I can support 99% of browsers in use with an amount of code that will occupy a single line the width of this comment.

Comment: `document.querySelector("label[for="+el.id+"]").style.display="none"` Just pass `this` from the inline handler, and bingo. And if we can rely on the positioning, then it's just `el.previousSibling.style.display="none";`

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Good stuff. I would convert it to an answer since it might be helpful for other people who want to solve this using standard JS

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thanks man! 

el.previousSibling.style.display="none";

is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

This hides the `label` of the corresponding `input`.

```
function focus() {
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i ++) {
        var attr = labels[i].getAttribute('for'); //or labels[i].htmlFor
        if(attr === this.id) {
            labels[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            //or labels[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

}

document.getElementById('ABC').addEventListener('focus', focus);
document.getElementById('DEF').addEventListener('focus', focus);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8r7xd/)

A jQuery solution:

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $('label[for=' + this.id + ']').hide();  
});
```

Comment: Although this works fine but for this function I will be needing to add "eventListener" lines for each element I want to hide... I want a function which is complete in itself and can refer to just any HTML DOM element without me needing to add a new line of code for it...

BTW thanks!

Comment: You can use a loop to attach a `focus` event for all `input`s. And the jQuery solution will work for all `input`s.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid `getAttribute()` you could use [`labels[i].htmlFor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement).

Comment: @Udit As c.P.u1 said you can use getElementsByTagName() to get the array of elements and then bind events to all of them. I have slightly modified c.P.u1's jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/8r7xd/2/

Comment: how about the radio button type. i want to hide label of other radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

+c.P.u1 jQuery solution can be written in standard JS for modern browsers (IE >=9) as follows

```
<label for="ABC">LABEL1</label><input type="text" id="ABC" onFocus="label(this);"/>
<label for="DEF">LABEL2</label><input type="text" id="DEF" onFocus="label(this);"/>

function label (el) {
  (el = document.querySelector ('label[for=" + el.id + '"]')) && 
    (el.style.display = 'none');
}
```

Note that we need to pass the `input` element as a parameter to the label function.

The fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/v5kZb/ shows a more structured way of doing this and also replaces the label when the input element loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat belated solution, and applies only to more up-to-date/modern browsers (basically, not Internet Explorer before version 8). This solution implements display-toggling (hiding the `label` when the `input` is focused, restoring it when the `input` is blurred):

Version one, taking advantage of the DOM structure:

```
// gets the first 'form' element:
var parentElement = document.querySelector('form');

function labelToggle (e) {
    // gets the target of the event ('e'),
    // the element that was focused or blurred:
    var self = e.target;
    // if the element has an 'id':
    if (self.id) {
        // get the previous sibling element
        var prev = self.previousElementSibling;
        // if it's 'display: none', change display to 'inline',
        // otherwise change to 'display: none':
        prev.style.display = prev.style.display == 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none';
    }
}

/* using event-delegation to avoid event-binding with a loop,
   using event-capturing to allow for an ancestor to listen for
   the 'non-bubbling' 'focus' and 'blur' events:
*/
parentElement.addEventListener('focus', labelToggle, true);
parentElement.addEventListener('blur', labelToggle, true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wn3xZ/).

Version two, using the `for` attribute (rather than the DOM structure):

```
// gets the first 'form' element:
var parentElement = document.querySelector('form');

function labelToggle (e) {
    // gets the target of the event ('e'),
    // the element that was focused or blurred:
    var self = e.target;
    // if the element has an 'id':
    if (self.id) {
        // get the label with the relevant 'for' attribute,
        // using CSS' attribute-equals notation:
        var label = this.querySelector('label[for="' + self.id + '"]');
        // if it's 'display: none', change display to 'inline',
        // otherwise change to 'display: none':
        label.style.display = label.style.display == 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none';
    }
}

parentElement.addEventListener('focus', labelToggle, true);
parentElement.addEventListener('blur', labelToggle, true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Wn3xZ/1/).

Obviously you can call the relevant functions by whatever name you prefer, I call them 'labelToggle' simply because I prefer a function-name to give some indication of what that function *does* when it's called.

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()` compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13).
- [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener).
- [`elementTraversal.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementTraversal.previousElementSibling).

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear, what you want to hide, label or textbox? However, here is an idea; it might help you.

```
<label for="ABC">LABEL1</label><input type="text" id="ABC" onFocus="label(this.id);"/>
<label for="DEF">LABEL2</label><input type="text" id="DEF" onFocus="label(this.id);"/>

function label(valID){
    var totalLabel= document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for(var l = 0; l < totalLabel.length; l++) {
        var lbb= totalLabel[l].getAttribute('for');
        if(lbb === valID) {
            labels[l].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to hide the label.

Comment: Its working fine for me. I did a try and while doing focus on the input area then associated label is hiding.

Answer (score -1):

> Jquery will be best suited for this. [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GXgg2/1/)

```
function hideLabel(element) {
        var name = $(element).attr("class");
        var lab = $("." + name)[0];
        $(lab).hide();

    }

    function showLabel(element) {
        var name = $(element).attr("class");
        var lab = $("." + name)[0];
        $(lab).show();
    }
```

> HTML

```
 <label class="a">
    Label1</label>
<input type="text" class="a" id="ABC" onfocus="hideLabel(this)" onblur="showLabel(this)" />
<label class="b">
    Label2</label>
<input type="text" class="b" id="DEF" onfocus="hideLabel(this)" onblur="showLabel(this)" />
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter but it appears the down vote was for jQuery solution whereas the OP asked for JavaScript (didn't mention jQuery)

Comment: its a generic and cross browser solution for other users also, suppose the condition when some other user ask same question with tag 'jquery'.

Comment: Take a loot at the Tag. If it says JavaScript, then stick to JavaScript. It is not necessary that someone looking for this solution has support jQuery in his/her project.

Comment: Don't know about the downvote, but you're missing the entire point of the `for` attribute on `<label>` elements and replacing it with your own notion of labels and elements being labeled being tied together by having the same class.